# Flash movie displays in IE, but not in Chrome

Tags: flash

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="230" height="130" align="right">
                  <param name="movie" value="images/10.swf" />
                  <param name="quality" value="high" />
                  <embed src="images/10.swf" width="230" height="130" align="right" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
                </object>
```

Why code above can't function in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, consider using one of the js libraries for embedding your flash files - even Adobe does it themselves on their site. The way browsers handle the object tag is not incredibly consistent.
The next thing I would look at is using a self closing embed tag -`<embed ... />`  instead of `<embed ... ></embed>`. Also consider looking at your doctype declaration.